# Why does the dimension of gradient and Hessian matrix not conform for this function?

Tags: least-squares, matrix, gradient, hessian, calculus

The function is $f(\mathbf{x}) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x^TAx}}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is a square symmetric matrix, and $\mathbf{x}$ is an n-vector.

What I found were:
$$
\begin{align*}
    \nabla f     &= \mathop{-e^{-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x^TAx}}}_{\text{what dimension is this}} \cdot \mathbf{\mathop{A}_{(n\times n)} \mathop{x}_{(n\times 1)}} \\
    \mathbf{H}_f &= \mathop{-e^{-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x^TAx}}}_{???} \cdot \mathbf{\mathop{A}_{(n\times n)}} + \mathop{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x^TAx}}}_{???} \cdot \mathbf{\mathop{A}_{(n\times n)} \mathop{x}_{(n\times 1)}} \cdot \mathbf{\mathop{A}_{(n\times n)} \mathop{x}_{(n\times 1)}}
\end{align*}
$$

However, if $\nabla f$ has the same dimension as $\mathbf{x}$, its dimension should be $\mathbf{(n\times 1)}$. Therefore $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x^TAx}}$ should have a dimension of $\mathbf{(n\times n)}$ (from equation above). Or even at least, it should have a dimension of $\mathbf{something\times n}$

To get my head around, $\mathbf{x^TAx}$ has dimension of $\mathbf{(1\times 1)}$ (or can I treat it as a scalar?). Thus I presume $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x^TAx}}$ also has a dimension of $\mathbf{(1\times 1)}$ (or scalar), but then...

$$
\begin{align*}
    1&. \text{This conflicts previous presumption;} \\
    2&. \text{How could I take the gradient on a scalar in the first place?}
\end{align*}
$$

I am confused.

Comment: $x^TAx$ multiplies matrices of dimension $(1 \times n), (n \times n), (n \times 1)$ together respectively, so what you get is a scalar.   A scalar times an $(n \times 1)$ matrix - which is what the product of $A$ and $x$ is - results in an $(n \times 1)$ matrix.  So you're good with your first equation.   Note that your equation for the Hessian isn't right, as the matrix dimensions in the last multiplications on the right hand side don't conform.

Comment: Your dimension counting is off and you are not differentiating correctly.  Because $x^\prime A x$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix it can be treated as a scalar and it decidedly is not an $n\times n$ matrix!  Indeed, $f$ is a scalar-valued function so you have *already* computed the graident of a scalar at the outset.

Comment: @jbowman So for the second equation, I should replace the last $\mathbf{Ax}$ with  $\mathbf{x^TA}$ to conform the dimension? Or should I treat $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x^TAx}}$ as scalar and don't use the product rule at all?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't applying the rules of matrix differentiation correctly.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=matrix+derivative for many examples that apply directly to your problem.